# SQL date_part returns the local timezone instead of the timezone in the argument

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT date_part('timezone_hour', '2019-12-01 13:37:12 PST'::timestamptz) AS "tz"
```

and

```
SELECT date_part('timezone_hour', '2019-12-01 13:37:12 EST'::timestamptz) AS "tz"
```

both return `-8`, my local pacific time GTM offset in hours instead of the timezone in the argument of the function.

The same behavior happens for extract:

```
SELECT extract('timezone_hour' from '2019-12-01 13:37:12 PST'::timestamptz) AS "year"
```

and

```
SELECT extract('timezone_hour' from '2019-12-01 13:37:12 PST'::timestamptz) AS "year"
```

both return `-8`.

Why don't I get the time zone offset that I specified for the timestamps?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?  Google BigQuery, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc?

Comment: And it is right behavior. Just check `select '2019-12-01 13:37:12 PST'::timestamptz as pst, '2019-12-01 13:37:12 EST'::timestamptz as est;` `timestamptz` does not store time zone information but converting value from local/specified time zone to UTC and then you can to convert it back to local/specified time zone (for local tame zone it happens implicitly).

Answer (score 2):

Try these:

```
SELECT date_part('hour', '2019-12-01 13:37:12'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'PST') AS "tz";
SELECT date_part('hour', '2019-12-01 13:37:12'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'EST') AS "tz";
SELECT date_part('hour', '2019-12-01 13:37:12'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'AEST') AS "tz";
```

These return 22, 19, and 4 respectively at [rextester (postgres)](http://rextester.com/MSGC7562)

In your existing approach if you pull the "timezone_hour" it will be the value you input (because that is the hour in that timezone).

Comment: I don't think that answers the question. OP wonders why he gets the same time zone even though he coded hist timestamp in different time zones.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Queries in question returns the same timezone hour - because he sends the same timezone value on each occasion. That is, 13:00 in Paris is 13:00; 13:00 in New York is 13:00; 13:00 in Vladivostok is 13:00. I thought that I had made that point. I believe it had been assumed that queries in the question would perform a timezone conversion, but it does not (in the question) do that.

Answer (score 0):

You'll understand better if you look at how PostgreSQL displays the two timestamps:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2019-12-01 13:37:12 PST';

      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2019-12-01 22:37:12+01
(1 row)

SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2019-12-01 13:37:12 EST';

      timestamptz       
------------------------
 2019-12-01 19:37:12+01
(1 row)
```

In both cases, the timestamp is converted to your session time zone, as specified by the `timezone` configuration parameter.

PostgreSQL does not store the time zone information in a `timestamp with time zone`, it converts the timestamp to UTC and stores it that way. Upon display, the timestamp is converted to the current session time zone.

So `timestamp with time zone` should better be called “absolute timestamp” in PostgreSQL. It accurately represents a certain point in time, but without time zone information.

In other words, if you extract `timezone_hour`, you will always get the same result: the time zone offset of your current session time zone.